# How to fake Ubuntu version number to applications

Tags: bash, versions

I'm trying to install Intel C++ compiler on Ubuntu 13.04, but the installation script says that only Ubuntu 12.10 and below are supported, and there is no option to force installation. So is there any way I can fake a version number to the installation script so it can install? I'm just experimenting, and not afraid to break the system.

Comment: can you provide a link to the script?

Comment: @strugee: It is contained in a large installation file (1.3GB).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> So is there any way I can fake a version number to the installation script so it can install?

Do you know how it tests for the version number? `/etc/lsb-release` contains...

```
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=13.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=raring
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 13.04"
```

and is a text file so you can edit this. It might be the file that is used to test what version you are using.