# Kubuntu 20.04.1 GUI system settings

Tags: kubuntu, gui, system-settings

What is the file from which Kubuntu reads details for version number of the operating system Kubuntu 20.04.1?
My version number in system settings is still Kubuntu 20.04. but the system is updated to 20.04.1.

It is possible to upgrade that file but not manually modified ?

Who has the Kubuntu 20.04.1 version can specify what version appear in system settings ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fake Ubuntu version number to applications](https://askubuntu.com/questions/292866/how-to-fake-ubuntu-version-number-to-applications)

Comment: In addition to the above, it is typically `/etc/lsb-release` that is used for release info. However, when upgrading to a point release, note that the `DISTRIB_RELEASE` is still `20.04`, but the `DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION` will be `Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS`. So it depends which field the app is reading. I'm not sure if it would break any compatibility to change the field `DISTRIB_RELEASE` to `20.04.1`